# Property 'nameFormControl' does not exist on type 'ContactComponent'

Tags: html, angular, forms, validation, components

Hello StackOverflow community!

I'm developing an app in Angular + Node and I've encountered a big issue regarding forms and validators using Material Angular.

At the moment, I'm stuck with the HTML component not recognizing the input, and I don't know what I'm missing.

I have this code:

*contact.component.html*:

```
<mat-card>
<mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Formulario de contacto</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Ponte en contacto conmigo</mat-card-subtitle>
</mat-card-header>
<form [formGroup]="contactForm">
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Nombre y apellidos</mat-label>
            <input matInput [formGroup]="contactForm" [formControl]="nameFormControl" required name="name" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
            @if (nameFormControl.hasError('required') || nameFormControl.hasError('pattern')) {
                <mat-error>Por favor, rellena este campo</mat-error>
            }
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Correo electrónico</mat-label>
            <input matInput [formControl]="emailFormControl" required name="email" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off">
            @if (emailFormControl.hasError('required')) {
                <mat-error>Por favor, rellena este campo</mat-error>
            }
            @else if (emailFormControl.hasError('email')) {
                <mat-error>Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida</mat-error>
            }
            @else if (emailFormControl.hasError('pattern')) {
                <mat-error>Debes introducir una dirección de correo electrónico válida</mat-error>
            }
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>
        <mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Mensaje</mat-label>
            <textarea #contactBody matInput [formControl]="bodyFormControl" name="body" maxlength="1024" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
            <mat-hint align="end">{{ contactBody.value.length }} / 1024</mat-hint>
            @if (bodyFormControl.hasError('required') || bodyFormControl.hasError('pattern')) {
                <mat-error>Por favor, rellena este campo</mat-error>
            }
        </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
</form>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveMessage()">Enviar formulario</button>
```

*contact.component.ts*:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AbstractControl, ReactiveFormsModule, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupDirective, NgForm, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppService } from './../app.service';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import { ErrorStateMatcher } from '@angular/material/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrl: './contact.component.scss'
})
export class ContactComponent implements ErrorStateMatcher {

  contactForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    nameFormControl: new FormControl(''),
    emailFormControl: new FormControl(''),
    bodyFormControl: new FormControl(''),
  })

  constructor(private appService: AppService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private _snackBar: MatSnackBar) {}

  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    const isSubmitted = form && form.submitted;
    return !!(control && control.invalid && (control.dirty || control.touched || isSubmitted));
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        nameFormControl: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/[\S]/)
          ]
        ], emailFormControl: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.email,
            Validators.pattern("^([a-zA-Z0-9-._]+)@([A-Za-z-]+)\.([a-z]{2,3}(.[a-z]{2,3})?)$")
          ]
        ], bodyFormControl: [
          '',
          [
            Validators.required,
            Validators.pattern(/[\S]/g)
          ]
        ]
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is on the **nameFormControl**, **emailFormControl** and **bodyFormControl**, which are under the FormGroup **contactForm**.

Can you guys bring me some light to this subject?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try removing `[formGroup]="contactForm"` from `<input matInput [formGroup]="contactForm" [formControl]="nameFormControl" required name="name" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" autofocus>` let me know if it work?

Comment: Hi @SelakaNanayakkara, unfortunately, it's still gives the same error

Comment: "NG9: Property 'nameFormControl' does not exist on type 'ContactComponent'". I tried to change the @if but it doesn't change either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FormGroup issue**

You should not set [formGroup] on your form fields and [formControl] should be formControlName

```
<!-- Incorrect -->
<input matInput [formGroup]="contactForm" [formControl]="nameFormControl"

<!-- Correct -->
<input matInput formControlName="nameFormControl"
```

**The @IF issue**

You can't access the control directly
You need to use the formGroup like this

```
@if (contactForm.controls.emailFormControl.hasError('required'))
```

Comment: That did the trick, but I still have the same issue on the @if condition statements

Comment: Edited my answher to explain the @IF issue

Answer (score 1):

You should use formControlName if you are using it inside FormGroup, and don't add [formGroup] on input fields. like this:

```
 <input matInput formControlName="nameFormControl" required name="name" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" autofocus>
```

Remove [formGroup] in the input fields and just replace the followings:

```
[formControl]="nameFormControl"
```

With this :

```
formControlName="nameFormControl"
```

Also you cannot access the control directly without the contactForm object.
So you need to replace following:

```
@if (emailFormControl.hasError('required'))
```

To:

```
@if (contactForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('required'))
```

**Tip:**
If you are using Visual Studio Code, then I would highly recommend using **Angular Language Service** Extension. It will show you the errors in the html file and help you fix them.

Also when you are using FormGroup, use can consider controls as the fields, so you can simply name them like this:

**nameFormControl** to **name**
**emailFormControl** to **email**
**bodyFormControl** to **body**

Like this:

```
  contactForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(''),
    email: new FormControl(''),
    body: new FormControl(''),
  })
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Danish Kumar! Solved

Answer (score 1):

**Couple things you need to correct in your template :**

1. Change your `[formControl]="nameFormControl"` to `formControlName="nameFormControl"` and follow the same to other controls as well
2. Remove `[formGroup]="contactForm"` from `nameFormControl`
3. Replace `@if (emailFormControl.hasError('required'))`  from `@if (contactForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('required'))`

Please find the corrected code below :

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>Formulario de contacto</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Ponte en contacto conmigo</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <form [formGroup]="contactForm">
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Nombre y apellidos</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="nameFormControl"
          required
          name="name"
          maxlength="128"
          autocomplete="off"
          autofocus
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Correo electrónico</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput
          formControlName="emailFormControl"
          required
          name="email"
          maxlength="128"
          autocomplete="off"
        />
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Mensaje</mat-label>
        <textarea
          #contactBody
          matInput
          formControlName="bodyFormControl"
          name="body"
          maxlength="1024"
          autocomplete="off"
        ></textarea>
        <mat-hint>{{ contactBody.value.length }} / 1024</mat-hint>
      </mat-form-field>
    </mat-card-content>
  </form>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="saveMessage()">
    Enviar formulario
  </button></mat-card
>
```

> Please refer the working stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-reactive-forms-validation-gf6xcq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fforms%2Fforms.component.html)

Comment: Thank you very much @Selaka nanayakkara ! Solved